# LineLocate a sequence of points, preserving order

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a linestring, which represents a bus route, and a sequence of points in order, representing the coordinates of each stop of that route. It kinda looks like this (pardon my poor drawing skills):
[image]

Basically, I want to get the total distance from the start of the route to each stop. I know this can be done by doing something like this:

```
SELECT stops.order,ST_LineLocatePoint(routes.line,stops.point)*ST_LineLength(routes.line)
FROM routes,stops
WHERE routes.route_id = stops.route_id
```

But the problem is that in the LineString, those two segments that are really close in the drawing (those that contain 5 and 8) actually overlap, so with that solution, stop 5 may be wrongly located between 8 and 9, or stop 8 between 5 and 6. But as I have the order of the stops, I suppose there must be a way to get the distances without getting those errors.
Maybe it cannot be done with a PostGIS function or query.

I have also thought about using ST_Line_Substring to "cut" the linestring, as I advance through each stop in order, but I still have the problem when 5 is located after 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not trivial; in general, a road network needs any form of linear reference/topology to be able to measure or route on and find relations between nodes/edges. The [*Linear Referencing*](https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Linear_Referencing) functions are immensely useful, but any 'closest point' derivations are limited to raw geometric proximity, and thus are ambiguous for cases like yours.

---

Now, since you seem to have one contiguous *Linestring* representing the road, you could try and hack your way around these problems with an [ST_OffsetCurve](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_OffsetCurve.html):

```
WITH
  offset AS (
    SELECT route_id,
           ST_Length(line) AS len,
           ST_OffsetCurve(line, <offset>, 'join=mitre') AS geom
    FROM  routes
  )

SELECT a.order,
       ST_LineLocatePoint(b.geom, a.point) * b.len AS dist
FROM   stops AS a
JOIN   offset AS b USING (route_id);
```

Here, a positive `<offset>` value will offset the resulting geometry to the left of the line (in line direction), and a negative value to the right; if we assume your *Linestring*s direction in the picture follows the bus stop order, you'd want to offset to the right. Then, however, the offset line direction will be reversed; you'd want to undo that, e.g. with

```
... ST_Reverse(ST_OffsetCurve(line, <offset>, 'join=mitre')) AS geom, ...
```

to get the `dist` values with respect to the bus stop order.

The `<offset>` value is interpreted as units of the data's CRS; since the function doesn't allow for the `GEOGRAPHY` type, you will either need to pass in *degrees*, for a geographic CRS (e.g. EPSG:4236), or transform your data in a suitable projection, with e.g. *meter* as unit. In any case, you'd need only a tiny offset, e.g. `0.000001` in *degrees*.

Note that this similarly applies to `ST_Length`; if you pass in a `GEOMETRY` in a geographic CRS, you'd get back the length in *degrees*, which are quite meaningless. If you are not working in a projected CRS, consider using the `GEOGRAPHY` type (only possible from EPSG:4326) to get (very precise) measurements in *meter*, e.g.

```
... ST_Length(line::GEOGRAPHY) AS len, ...
```

---

Be aware that this is a workaround with limited robustness and tailored to your presented case!

Comment: Clear answer, and using offset works like a charm. Thank you very much!